# Salesforce: Angularjs and Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku

I am folloiwng the tutorial mentioned in the below URL.

https://developer.salesforce.com/mobile/getting-started/html5/#angularjs-heroku

I followed exactly as mentioned, I am able to OAuth successfully, I am able to create a contact and that gets saved, but during contact list view, I am getting the following error.

### Error:

> Calling errorCB for forcetkClient:query
>
> Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" GET
>   https://peaceful-gorge-3898.herokuapp.com/proxy/?_=1406084316812 400
>   (Bad Request)
>
> function (){if(a){var n=a.length;(function
>   s(t){x.each(t,function(t,n){var
>   r=x.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&c.has(n)||a.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&s(n)})})(arguments),r?o=a.length:t&&(i=n,l(t))}return
>   this}

---

I am getting this error at this point.

```
function ContactListCtrl($scope, AngularForce, $location, Contact) {
    if (!AngularForce.authenticated()) {
        return $location.path('/home');
    }

    $scope.searchTerm = '';
    $scope.working = false;

    Contact.query(function (data) {
        $scope.contacts = data.records;
        $scope.$apply();//Required coz sfdc uses jquery.ajax
    }, function (data) {
        console.log(' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Error : ' + data.error);
        alert('Query Error : ' + data.error);
        $scope.contacts = data.records;

    });
```

Did anybody encounter any such error?

Comment: I see you've also asked this question in the Salesforce Developer Community: http://goo.gl/zCoRFl. Anywhere else?

Comment: Which browwser (incl. version) are you using? Which operating system?

Comment: It looks like the user-agent header is being set here: https://github.com/developerforce/MobilePack-AngularJS/blob/master/samples/AngularHerokuBootstrapNode/public/js/sdk/forcetk.mobilesdk.js#L101 . What happens if you comment that out?